# Blocking Multiple Failed Postfix AUTH Attempts with CSF

Tags: linux, firewalls

I am using CSF/LFD on my CentOS 7 server, and would like to use it to temporarily block IP addresses that have multiple failed Postfix AUTH attempts. You know the one, I get line after line of:

```
lost connection after AUTH from host.example.com[123.123.123.123]
```

Once perhaps 6 of these have happened, I would like to block the IP for a while. I know this can be [done with fail2ban](https://serverfault.com/questions/335983/postfix-connection-lost-after-auth/705020#705020) but I am using CSF. I have looked around for info but can't figure out how it can be achieved. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. [CSF Cheat Sheet](https://www.hostdime.com/resources/csf-ssh-command-line-commands/)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't show how to do what I need but useful to know about.

Comment: It shows how to add temporary ips to a whitelist/blacklist and how to remove them. Is not what you need? Of course you'll need a script to check logs for the failed attempts before launch the CSF command, but that's all. Maybe your question is more related to how to do a bash script.

Comment: LFD scans log files regularly as a daemon process. I want to know how to configure LFD to pick up on these entries too, and then set up a temporary ban. Writing a script would mean it had to run every few seconds as a cron job which is precisely what LFD is designed to avoid being necessary. So that wouldn't work. Thanks though.